# Magento license doubts

Tags: license

I'm boginning with a startup that's based on online shops.
Something kinda shopify.
I'm investigating into wich platform better suites my needs, and Magento appears to be the first choice.
I only have one doubt, that's regarding to it's license limitations.

My project is basically a site where you can create your own online store. I provide hosting, a Magento installation with some themes and limitations, and charge a percentage of each monthly period sales.
Can I do that with a community license? Do I need an enterprise license? Is there another option?

Hope you guys can help me.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you might want to look into the partner program.  There are requirements to it, but you get some benefits like being labeled as a partner for the platform. See: https://magento.com/become-a-partner

As far as the edition is concerned, the Enterprise version does come with limitations like the number of domains you can use it for.  I haven't renewed my enterprise license yet this year so I'm not sure of the current wording; however, our current license limits it to a certain number of domains a single installation can have.  In previous terms they also limited you to the number of servers you could have the code on.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know *(magento gurus, correct me if I am wrong)*, generally speaking, the major difference comes to scalability between two solutions. Community edition is open source, you have NO support from Magento, be prepared to get your hands dirty if something goes spiral. Plus there are some features available in Enterprise edition that MOST small business owners will not even consider using (auto RMA, Gift registry, SAP integration, etc) whereas larger businesses would implement. Plus 15k/year is insignificant amount for a large corporation, given that Enterprise edition would be much more efficient handling hundred thousand of products vs Community, plus direct support from Magento team itself.
You are also limited to the number of domain used per license agreement.

There are extensions that can expand Community edition to the level of Enterprise, feature wise. But again, you are on your own.

So if you are small business owner, and don't plan to expand to the level of Home Depot, community should do.

All said is IMO.

Comment: Scalability is the same.  The EE really just adds functionality via modules; however, it's still based on the CE edition.  Probably the most notable addition is PCI compliance.  The CE *can* be compliant, but it takes some work.  The EE comes as a compliant base and any extensions you add need to be validated or provide their own validation.  This is not to say CE is insecure, just that it lacks some of the logging required by PCI DSS.